# Error when targeting ES5 in TypeScript with Async Iteration and running on the browser

Tags: typescript

Following [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html) for "Generation and Iteration for ES5", I added the following polyfill:

```
(Symbol as any).asyncIterator = Symbol.asyncIterator || Symbol.for("Symbol.asyncIterator");
```

This causes my browser to throw an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property ‘asyncIterator’ of function ‘function Symbol() { [native code] }’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the property is readonly, only assign it when it doesn't exist:

```
if (typeof (Symbol as any).asyncIterator  === 'undefined') {
 (Symbol as any).asyncIterator = Symbol.asyncIterator || Symbol('asyncIterator');
}
```